# Python library to dl youtube videos with highest resolution in colab

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl, pytube

I want to be download videos in 1080p/720p etc fast in google colab.
so I found the `pytube` but apparently it doesn't support 1080p vids.

```
from pytube import YouTube
link = "    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv91YPlFmQA       ".replace(' ','')

yt = YouTube(link)  

print(yt.streams.get_highest_resolution())
```

max quality here is 720p but the video has 1080p and btw the downloading speed was very high and can download 2GB videos in secs.

so I tried

```
youtube_dl_options = {
    "format": "mp4[height=1080]", # This will select the specific resolution typed here
    "outtmpl":'/content/drive/MyDrive/' +"%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s",
    "restrictfilenames": True,
    "nooverwrites": True,
    "writedescription": True,
    "writeinfojson": True,
    "writeannotations": True,
    "writethumbnail": True,
    "writesubtitles": True,
    "writeautomaticsub": True
}
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
link = "     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv91YPlFmQA     ".replace(' ','')
downloadLinks = [link]

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(youtube_dl_options) as ydl:
    ydl.download(downloadLinks)
```

it has 1080p but its downloading speed is super low like 70KB/s, so is there any other library to download youtube vids at a better speed with 1080p resolution.

so if u know a way that I can dl 1080p with pytube (ofc with audio) in colab, or anyway to make `youtube-dl` faster or any other way that can provide this functionalities please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The highest resolution for combined audio and video is 720p.

YouTube streaming data contains higher resolution videos, but they do not contain audio. These videos are **DASH** (Dynamic Adaptive Stream over HTTP), ie, individual stream of video only data, or audio only data.

You could use other library like **ffmpeg** to merge the audio and video streams to get higher resolution files. I have done it in my notebook, please have a look and see if the code is useful to you:

https://github.com/JNYH/pytube/blob/master/pytube_sample_code.ipynb

Bonus: I have also included OAuth log in (use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True) to access age-restricted videos and private videos (with given access).